# How to maintain a custom block content?

Tags: forms

I have created a block using a custom module.

In the block, I have static text which will vary by time; thus, I will have to let the content manager decide when to modify the static text.

Could any one tell what is the best approach should I follow?

Note: I don't want the content manager to edit the text from the code.

Answer (score 0):

have you considered adding a standard HTML block at

Admin > Structure > Blocks > Add Block ?

`/admin/structure/block/add`

Drupal provides a standard interface for editing the HTML block content.

Alternatively, if you have PHP code, combined with alot of static text in the block, you could load a node into it instead, and use regular node editing for maintaining that text content.

e.g, in `hook_block_view`

```
$node = node_load($nid); // Load the text content from node
// PHP logic to build some content...
// ...
$block['content'] = $data; // php content
$block['content'] .= render(node_view($node)); // node content
```

Comment: I cant have node loaded, block which I have created has certain logic, which is too complex. any other idea?

Comment: You can load some content from the node, and some with your php logic.